# What are the new 'p' variables in Android Studio debugger variables pane?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-debugger

Recently I've installed the Bumblebee version of Android Studio and I've remarked strange new fields marked with `p` icon and `...get()` in my debugger variables pane.
I haven't found any info about these fields, so maybe you can answer? They are so annoying, just duplicating info about `val` fields in the class.
See the screenshots and the sample class:

```
data class MyOwnClass2(
    val fieldOne: String,
    val fieldTwo: Int,
)
```

I'm using coroutines in the app, and have some Java code mixed with Kotlin one.
I can only imagine that these fields are 'properties' of the class, but I didn't explicitly override custom get/set.

[image: breakpoint example]
[image: annoying duplicated fields]

Answer (score 0):

TL;TR: `@JvmField` or migrate from Java!

So after all, these are consequences of using both Kotlin and Java code in the same module. When I put `@JvmField`, it doesn't generate these get/set in Kotlin, so no 'p' fields in the debugger are seen any longer.